# Date format missing in admin grid and admin form in magento 2 custom module?

Tags: grid, adminform, magento2.3.2, date

I created a custom module to update news and stories to magento 2 website.I have the date field in my form( **main.php** ).

```
 $dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(
        \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM
    );
 $timeFormat = $this->_localeDate->getTimeFormat(
        \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM
    );

 $fieldset->addField(
        'news_date',
        'date',
        [
            'name' => 'news_date',
            'label' => __('News date'),
            'title' => __('News date'),
            'date_format' => $dateFormat,
            //'time_format' => $timeFormat,
            'required' => true,
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );
```

My grid file is like below.

```
this->addColumn(
        'news_date',
        [
            'header' => __('News date'),
            'index' => 'news_date',
            'type'      => 'date',
        ]
    );
```

What my issue is actual saved date is not showing in grid.if i save the news for **Oct 29, 2019** grid will show **Oct 28, 2019**.
Below attached two images.

**form**
[image]

**Grid**
[image]

What is the issue behind this? Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happening because of Time Zone Problem:

```
Go to Configuration > General > locale Options > Time Zone
```

**Set the Server time zone and Magento Time zone same for this Problem.**

Hope this will help You!!

Comment: thank you. this helped me

Comment: My Pleasure....